# configure box2D for visual studio using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, box2d

I am trying to install box2D for visual studio 15. 
I am currently following this tutorial: https://aneelkkhatri.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/setting-up-box2d-library-in-visual-studio-c/.

Using cmake, I have selected the path to the box2D source code folder:

> C:/Users/****/Desktop/Box2D-master/Box2D

and where to build it:

> C:/Users/****/Desktop/Box2D-master/Box2D/Build

Then i select configure and choose my VS version. cmake loads for a few seconds then i get this error:

> You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library glfw without any source files.
>   This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file

But it continues and i get the msg configuration done. I press configure again and then generate. Now i get an error popup saying Error in generation process, project files may be invalid. I check the log and it now says:

> CMake Error at Testbed/CMakeLists.txt:84 (add_executable):   Cannot
>   find source file:
>
> ```
> Framework/imgui.h
> ```
>
> Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
>   .hpp   .hxx .in .txx
>
> CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: glfw

After this message it says Generating done. I go into my build folder and open Box2d.sln, VS opens but in the log it says:

> C:\Users****\Desktop\Box2D-master\Box2D\Build\glfw\glfw.vcxproj :
>   error  : Project
>   "C:\Users****\Desktop\Box2D-master\Box2D\Build\glfw\glfw.vcxproj"
>   could not be found.

I try to compile the solution but i get the pop up error:

> Unable to start program
>   'C:\Users****\Desktop\Box2D-master\Box2D\Build\Debug\ALL_BUILD' The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

What am i doing wrong here? What does all these errors mean? I have followed 3 different tutorials but i get the same error? Where is my cmakelists.txt and how should i edit it so it works?

Comment: ***What am i doing wrong here?*** It could be a problem with the documentation. I mean CMake version 2.8.4 is really old.

Comment: ***Unable to start program 'C:\Users****\Desktop\Box2D-master\Box2D\Build\Debug\ALL_BUILD' The system cannot find the file specified.*** ALL_BUILD is not an executable target. You need to change the startup project to something that is.

Comment: Thanks for the input, you addressed the errror i got in VS. I think that error derives from the previous errors somehow. How do i change the startup project?

Comment: Right click on a target that is an application in solution explorer. The selection will be in the menu.

Comment: BTW, The `CMake` steps look pretty standard even though the version in the picture is 5 years old.

Comment: Thanks but i dont really now what executable i need to change to, if its missing box2D obviously dont include it. Where do i get the executable ALL_BUILD?

Comment: ***Where do i get the executable ALL_BUILD*** ALL_BUILD is not an executable. It is a target used to force the building of other targets. You can not run ALL_BUILD. I know this because I use `CMake` for 8+ years. Every CMake based project has this target in visual studio. You must set some other target (that is an executable) to be the startup target if you want to debug. I have not downloaded the project so I can't answer that.